# The font in documentation is thinner than normal

Tags: bug, design

On Stack Overflow and other sites, the text at the top bar is like this:

[image]

But on documentation, the strokes of the text appears to be thinner: (maybe there is a special term for this, I dunno)

[image]

Do you see the difference?

I'm using Safari 9.1.2 (11601.7.7) btw.

And I can't reproduce on Chrome. Maybe you missed a `webkit-` thingy? (Note: I know little about this. I might say stupid things)

Comment: [`vendor prefix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) is the technical term that you're after! =)

Comment: Both Chrome and Safari are WebKit-based, by the way.

Comment: Check your zoom levels.

Comment: @TinyGiant There's no problem with my zoom levels

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Technically Chrome forked WebKit into [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink), but many of the `-webkit` prefixes are being used by lots of rendering engines these days...

Comment: I can reproduce this on Ask Different too!

Comment: I can repro this - Xubuntu 15.10 in Chrome 52.0.2743.75 beta (64-bit).  The difference on my screen is ***very*** slight but it's there.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: That's why he said "WebKit-based" - Blink retains a lot of legacy code from WebKit, including proprietary prefixes that aren't described in the [WHATWG compat spec](https://compat.spec.whatwg.org) (the ones that are, are the same ones recognized by competing layout engines like Gecko and EdgeHTML), along with the bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I have reported it in the first stage of private beta. (when the documentation resided in http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com, now redirects to Stack Overflow). Looks like out private-beta posts are somewhere in another universe, probably they will appear with the public beta launch.

So, this happens with those floating tips enabled - if you disable them, the text is getting its normal "strength".

> [image]